# How to get row and col from e with onEdit

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to get the coordinates of the modified cell with a script in order to perform some actions, in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) I see that `e.range` returns a range object, so according to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
if I'm not mistaking, I should be able to perform `e.range.getRow()` or `e.range.getCol()`.
I tried this :

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const RANGE = e.range;

  let row = RANGE.getRow();
  let col = RANGE.getCol();

  Logger.log('line : ', row, 'column : ', col)
}
```

but nothing happens except this in th executions tab:

```
TypeError: RANGE.getCol is not a function  
    at onEdit(script:5:19)
```

Whet am I doing wrong?

Comment: `e.range.columnStart` is the column number of the edit and `e.range.rowStart` is the row number of the edit.  You can also get the sheet with `e.range.getSheet()`  By doing it this way you avoid the use of any functions and you function runs much faster which is important for a function that must complete in 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Use the properties of the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) as Cooper recommends. To answer your question, the `Range()` object does not have a `.getCol()` method. The correct method is `.getColumn()`.

See these [onEdit(e) optimization tips](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/155429/269219).